# Adding a jquery timepicker to dynamically added input fields in a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, timepicker

i have a code for dynamically generated input fields in a table using clone() method of jquery.the code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable tr:last input").live("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().clone().appendTo("#myTable");
    });

    });
```

my html code for the table is as follows

```
<table id="myTable" class="timingtable" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="width:100%; height:170px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Start time</th>
    <th>End time</th>
    <th>Family</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="start" id="element1" class="datefield" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="end" id="element2" class="datefield" value="" ></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="date" name="start" id="element3" class="datefield" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="end" id="element4" class="datefield" value="" ></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="start" id="element5" class="datefield" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="end" id="element6" class="datefield" value="" ></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="start" id="element7" class="datefield" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="end" id="element8" class="datefield" value="" ></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="date" name="start" id="element9" class="datefield" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="end" id="element10" class="datefield" value="" ></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="date" name="start" id="element11" class="datefield" value=""  /></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="start" id="element12" class="datefield" value=""/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i have added timepicker to the input fields as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.datefield').timepicker();
        });
```

datefield is the class name given to static input fields.

i am getting timepicker to static fields but i am not getting timepicker to the dynamically generated input fields.

what i have to do for getting timepicker to the dynamically generated fields also.please provide a solution for this problem.

thanks in advance.......

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().clone().appendTo("#tableID")..timepicker();

Comment: i tried the above code.but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the ID of the timepicker field manually. and then apply the timepicker to the dynamically added field. Only this will work. because timepicker works with the ID of the element.

Also

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tableID tr:last input").live("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().clone().appendTo("#tableID");
    });

    });
```

instead of this Use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tableID tr:last input").live("click",function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo("#tableID");
    });

    });
```

Comment: not only id, names also should vary dynamically, otherwise in successor page you will be in trouble for receiving the values

Comment: so what to do for changing the names dynamically

Comment: var tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
using this tr variable you can target the input fields in this tr and then you change the id by input.attr('id', newId)

Comment: a new row is being added,but when i click on that row the timepicker is coming in the previous row itself,the value i entered is not displaying in the new row

Comment: You are not getting this. Unless you change the IDs of the input boxes of the newly Added row. If you don't change the ID then timepicker always will be open for the cloned row.

Comment: yes i understood what you said.can u please show me how to do that in the code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4NnE6/7/ go to this fiddle. timepicker is not added there. But the Ids of the newly added input boxes get changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12420/discussion-between-user1334095-and-zahid-riaz)

Comment: Check the fiddle now. Its working now. I've added another timepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Just one doubt why do you need to both id and class ?

I had a similar requirement i did with class only ... since id caters to uniqueness.

check the below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/manmohan_menon/6YkyY/4/

Comment: I have one question for you, in my project I have to populate my table after I select start time, end time and interval that can be from 5 min up to 60min. For example: start time 8am, interval 15min and end time will be 5pm. So ia have to create <tr> with start time 8am - 8:15am then next <tr> with start time 8:15am -  8:30am and all the way until I hit 5pm but not grater than that. I know that I have to use for loop and inside to build my tr. But my question is who to implement time values in the for loop for start and end time. I have to convert them. Do you know how I can do that?